# Remember me for login does not work in the server but in the local work very good

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

if you login now to [Lotusoi](https://lotusoi.com) with remember me and do nothing for 5 minutes, you will need to login again.

but if i run my web app in local, it work very good.

i tried debug my app and the remember me already true and sign in successfully and persistent login work very good in local only but when publish my app and upload it in host , it will not be persistent with remember me = true.

my code is scafolding for individual authentication

my login function

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == model.Email || x.UserName == model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
        if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
        {

            string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, 
                "Welcome to lotusoi", "Hi ,Confirm your email address to help us ensure your account is always protected in lotusoi.at<br><a style='border:none;color:#fff;background:#665cac;width:105px;padding:10px;display:block;font-size:16px;border-radius:360px;text-decoration:none' href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">Confirm Now</a>");
            TempData["userId"] = user.Id;
            return RedirectToAction("EmailConfirmation");
        }
        if (await UserManager.IsLockedOutAsync(user.Id))
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user,model.RememberMe,model.RememberMe);
                if (model.RememberMe)
                {
                    var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                    var d = cookie.Expires;
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
                else
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                }
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

i tried to use this code but does not work

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

my Startup.Auth.cs as default

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))

                }
            });            
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
            app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

            // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
            // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
            // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
            app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IIS application pool may be timing out due to inactivity. By default the application pools terminate after a certain amount of time and doing so kills your sessions so even if you have persistent logins enabled and the user has a long duration authentication cookie to login they may need to login again if the app pool shuts down due to inactivity. You can change this in the IIS settings by doing the following:

- Go to the `Application pools` tab in IIS manager
- Right click the app pool you're currently using and select `Advanced Settings`
- Set the `Idle Time-out(minutes)` to a higher value or `0` for it to never terminate
- Restart the app pool

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for caught my attention for that so this is problem with idel in IIS for server not with my code i tried to change this idle time out is server but i can not so i spoke now to support for this server